# add view on existing imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, cover

I want to cover existing imageview with another view which just has black background and i want its size to be equal to the imageview but the height doesn't work properly

That's my code :

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/feedImage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/cover" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/playBackground"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"                        
                        android:background="#75000000" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/playIcon"
                            android:layout_width="110dp"
                            android:layout_height="110dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/play" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

That's the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/feedImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/cover" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/playBackground"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"                        
                    android:background="#75000000" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/playIcon"
                        android:layout_width="110dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/play" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your second `ImageView` change your **layout_height** and your **layout_width** by **match_parent** value.

Comment: it is very big and i want to resize it corresponding to screen size

Comment: no when you use match parent, it take the size of your relative_layout that contain this ImageView

Comment: I solved it with framelayout instead of Relative .. Thanks :)